# Rows.Count generates runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I keep getting run-time error 1004, when trying to use `Rows.Count`. It usually occurs the first time I run the code below, but if I reset and run again it works.

It is failing on this line:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
```

Any help with getting this code to run reliably would be greatly appreciated!

The code in its entirety is as follows:

```
Private Sub ImportAPRData_Click()
'Declare variables for columns in "Projects" spreadsheet in Approved Reliability Projects Workbook (Excel)
Dim orgSheetCol(13) As String
    orgSheetCol(0) = "$E$" 'Project Title
    orgSheetCol(1) = "$D$" 'Circuit Tag
    orgSheetCol(2) = "$F$" 'District
    orgSheetCol(3) = "$G$" 'State
    orgSheetCol(4) = "$M$" 'Date recieved
    orgSheetCol(5) = "$J$" 'Planned Capital Cost
    orgSheetCol(6) = "$X$" 'Actual Capital Cost
    orgSheetCol(7) = "$U$" 'Capital work completed date
    orgSheetCol(8) = "$K$" 'Planned O&M Cost
    orgSheetCol(9) = "$Y$" 'Actual O&M Cost
    orgSheetCol(10) = "$V$" 'O&M work completed date
    orgSheetCol(11) = "$AD$" 'Path to RWP file
    orgSheetCol(12) = "I" 'Investment Reason


'Declare variables for cell values attained from APR spreadsheet
Dim orgSheetvalues(13) As Variant
    orgSheetvalues(0) = "" 'Project Title
    orgSheetvalues(1) = "" 'Circuit Tag
    orgSheetvalues(2) = "" 'District
    orgSheetvalues(3) = "" 'State
    orgSheetvalues(4) = "" 'Date recieved
    orgSheetvalues(5) = ""  'Planned Capital Cost
    orgSheetvalues(6) = ""  'Actual Capital Cost
    orgSheetvalues(7) = ""  'Capital work completed date
    orgSheetvalues(8) = ""  'Planned O&M Cost
    orgSheetvalues(9) = ""  'Actual O&M Cost
    orgSheetvalues(10) = ""  'O&M work completed date
    orgSheetvalues(11) = "" 'RWP File Path
    orgSheetvalues(12) = "" 'Investment Reason


'Declare & Set Variables for opening & working with Excel Wrokbook / worksheet (Approved Relaibility Projects/Projects)
 Dim xls     As Excel.Application
 Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet
 Set xls = New Excel.Application

'Delcare & set variables for loops, excel row, cell numbers, etc.
 Dim rownumber As Integer
 rownumber = 3
 Dim rowstring As String
 Dim cellstring As String
 Dim i As Integer
'Declare & set variable to see if RWP already exists in table
 Dim tablecheck As Integer
 tablecheck = 0
'Declare variable for Capital and O&M Costs / completion dates conditions
 Dim Condition1 As Boolean
 Dim Condition2 As Boolean
 Dim Condition3 As Boolean
 Dim Condition4 As Boolean
 Dim Condition5 As Boolean
 Dim Condition6 As Boolean
 Dim Condition7 As Boolean
 Dim Condition8 As Boolean
 Dim LastRow As Integer



'Open Approved Reliability Projects Workbook & set worksheet to "Projects"
 xls.Visible = True
 xls.UserControl = True
 Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("\\pacificorp.us\dfs\SLCCO\SHR02\PD\POWER\AreaSystemFiles\UT\Park_City_Office\Reliability\RWP_Goal_Tracking\Approved Reliability Projects v5.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
 Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Projects")

 'Find row # for last populated row
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'For some reason it keeps giving me an error here!!!!
 'For each row in APR spreadsheet get info, then make sure all criteria are met, then check to see if it already exists in table, if not insert into table
 For rownumber = 3 To LastRow
    rowstring = CStr(rownumber)
    'Pull information from specified row in APR Spreadsheet
     For i = 0 To 12
         cellstring = orgSheetCol(i) & rowstring
         orgSheetvalues(i) = wks.Range(cellstring).Value
         If IsError(orgSheetvalues(i)) Then
             orgSheetvalues(i) = wks.Range(cellstring).Text
         End If
     Next i

     'Check to make sure that there are planned costs and completion dates before inserting into rwpT Table
     Condition1 = orgSheetvalues(5) <> "" And (orgSheetvalues(7) <> "" And orgSheetvalues(7) <> "#") And orgSheetvalues(11) Like "\\*"
     Condition2 = orgSheetvalues(5) = "" And orgSheetvalues(7) = "" And orgSheetvalues(11) Like "\\*"
     Condition3 = orgSheetvalues(8) <> "" And orgSheetvalues(10) <> "" And orgSheetvalues(10) <> "N/A"
     Condition4 = orgSheetvalues(8) = "" And orgSheetvalues(10) = ""
     Condition5 = Condition1 And Condition3
     Condition6 = Condition1 And Condition4
     Condition7 = Condition1 And Condition3
     Condition8 = (Condition5 Or Condition6) Or Condition7
     If Condition8 Then
        tablecheck = DCount("PlanTitle", "rwpT", "PlanTitle = '" & orgSheetvalues(0) & "'") 'check rwp table to see if plan is already there
        'If plan is not there insert into rwpT Table
        If tablecheck = 0 Then
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO rwpT (PlanTitle, Circuit, OpArea, State, InvestmentReason, ApprovalDate, PlanCapitalCost, ActualCapitalCost, CapitalWorkCompDate, PlanOMCost, ActualOMCost, OMWorkCompDate, File) Values ('" & orgSheetvalues(0) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(1) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(2) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(3) & "','" & orgSheetvalues(12) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(4) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(5) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(6) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(7) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(8) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(9) & "', '" & orgSheetvalues(10) & "','" & orgSheetvalues(11) & "')"
        End If
     End If
 Next rownumber

'Close Approved Reliability Projects Workbook & remove all handles to it
 wkb.Close False 'Close workbook.  False is so that it doesn't save
 Set wks = Nothing
 Set wkb = Nothing
 xls.Quit
 Set xls = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Dim LastRow As Integer` to `Dim LastRow As Long` and it will be fine, there are too many rows to have as an integer.

In VBA it's actually good practice to always use Long instead of Integer as they are both stored as longs then the integer is converted at runtime, do a search on here for more info on it.

Comment: If the calculation of `LastRow` determined a number greater than is valid for an `Integer` the error would be an error 6 ("Overflow") rather than an error 1004.  So, although it is highly desirable that the `Integer` be changed to `Long`, it won't be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not have a default `Rows` property (or if it does, it isn't what you want to use).  You want to use `Rows` in its Excel sense which, if run within an Excel application would default to `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows`.

Because Access doesn't know what `Rows` means, it uses the property from a default instance of the Excel Application object (which is different to your `xls` object).  The default instance doesn't have a workbook open in it, or a worksheet, so it can't determine what `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows` (or `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells`) means.

---

Change the line saying

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
```

so that you fully qualify your methods/properties, i.e.

```
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
```